# How to put date filters in search.create() through suitescript 2.0?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have made a `userEvent` script (`afterSubmit` function) on Invoice record. In my script i m creating a search in which in m applying 2 filters on `startdate` and `enddate`. I actually need to filter out the line that have `startdate` and `enddate`in which my invoice's `trandate` lays.
[image: This is the view of the same search as savedsearch]

For example if my trandate is 28/5/2020, than results should show only this line as follows: (because my date resides in between that specific line's start date and end date)
[image]

Kindly help/suggest anything, I m confused because my results comes out as an empty array when I apply the following code:

my code:

```
    /* search */
      var ssFilters = [];

      // /* START date */
      ssFilters.push(search.createFilter({
        "name": "custrecord25",// start date
        "operator": search.Operator.ONORAFTER,
        "values": invTranDate
      }));
      // /* END date */
      ssFilters.push(search.createFilter({
        "name": "custrecord26",// end date
        "operator": search.Operator.ONORBEFORE,
        "values": invTranDate
      }));
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use one filter and will need to use the WITHIN operator:

```
ssFilters.push(search.createFilter({
    "name": "custrecord26",
    "operator": search.Operator.WITHIN,
    "values": [startDate, endDate]
  }));
```

Good luck!